# Align text in the center of <p> element

Tags: html, css

Let me know how to align text in the center of 'p' element.

I think Aligning text in p element is not same as aligning text in div element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <style>
        #element{
            background: #95CFEF;
            border: solid 1px #36F;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px auto;
         text-align: center;
        }
        </style>
        <body>
        <p id = "element">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/sri276286/w65jLzv9/

I am expecting like this:

[image]

Comment: What have   you tried?

Comment: Please find the fiddle attached and I want the text to be center of that element

Comment: It looks like you're asking for both vertical and horizontal alignment?. Right now you're doing horizontal alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try `line-height: 100px;`

Basically line-height should be same as your `#element's` height

Comment: This worked. Thanks

Comment: I don't have enough points to accept your answer

Comment: @SrinkathReddyKarnati - yes you do, there is no points requirement to accept - that's the whole point

Answer (score -2):

It's not `id = "element"`, it's `id="element"` mind the spaces. This could fix your problem. If you meant vertical align let me know and I'll come back on that

Comment: That's not a big deal. I tried removing that space but still issue. I want that text to be exactly at center of that paragraph element

Comment: This is not useful - Those are equivalent (the spacing change has no impact) You can prove it to yourself in a simple jsfiddle.